# XPage datatable and pager issue

Tags: datatable, xpages

On my XPage, I have a series of search filters (State, First Name and Last Name). The search button triggers the population of the datatable which is bound to a Managed Bean.

The datatable initially gets populated with rows of data. However when I click on Next (in the pager), instead of loading the next 5 rows, it returns no more data. I KNOW the datatable is getting the right number of rows because if I change the Repeat limit in the datatable to 10, they all display. Also, the number of pages in the pager is 2 (which is the correct number).

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Thanks,

Dan

Code for the datatable:

```
    <xp:dataTable rows="5" id="studentTable" var="currentStudent"
        style="width:400.0px" value="#{studentlist.students}">
        <xp:column id="firstnameColumn" style="font-weight:bold">
            <xp:this.facets>
                <xp:span xp:key="header">
                    <xp:span style="font-weight:bold">
                        First Name
                    </xp:span>
                </xp:span>
            </xp:this.facets>
            <xp:text escape="true" id="firstnameField"
                value="#{currentStudent.firstname}">
            </xp:text>
        </xp:column>
        <xp:column id="column1">
            <xp:text escape="true" id="middleinitialField"
                value="#{currentStudent.middleName}">
            </xp:text>
            <xp:this.facets>
                <xp:span xp:key="header">
                    <xp:span style="font-weight:bold">
                        Middle Name
                    </xp:span>
                </xp:span>
            </xp:this.facets>
        </xp:column>
        <xp:column id="lastnameColumn" style="font-weight:bold">
            <xp:this.facets>
                <xp:span xp:key="header">
                    <xp:span style="font-weight:bold">
                        Last Name
                    </xp:span>
                </xp:span>
            </xp:this.facets>
            <xp:text escape="true" id="lastnameField"
                value="#{currentStudent.lastname}">
            </xp:text>
        </xp:column>
        <xp:column id="idColumn">
            <xp:this.facets>
                <xp:span xp:key="header">
                    <xp:span style="font-weight:bold">ID</xp:span>
                </xp:span>
            </xp:this.facets>               
            <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1"
                value="#{currentStudent.id}">
            </xp:text>
        </xp:column>
        <xp:this.facets>
            <xp:pager layout="Previous Group Next" xp:key="header"
                id="pager1" for="studentTable" partialRefresh="true">
            </xp:pager>
        </xp:this.facets></xp:dataTable>
```

Code behind the button:

```
    var state=getComponentValue('state');
    var firstName=document1.getItemValueString("firstName");
    var lastName=document1.getItemValueString("lastName");
    if(state == "--" || firstName == "" || lastName == "")
    {
    //do nothing
    }
    else{
    studentlist.setConnDB("jdbc:sqlserver://XX.XX.X.XX:1433;DatabaseName=dan_test");
    studentlist.setConnUserName("test");
    studentlist.setConnPassword("Password1");
    studentlist.setSQLQuery("SELECT FirstName,MiddleName,LastName,ID FROM TestStudents        WHERE FirstName Like '"+firstName+"%' AND LastName Like '"+lastName+"%' AND State = '"+state+"' ORDER BY LastName ASC");
```

Comment: Can you post any of the code? Otherwise we're just guessing. ;)

Comment: Thanks Tim. I've updated the post with my code for the button  and the source for the datatable. Appreciate your input.

Dan

Comment: I've seen a demo of this - though I don't know the answer off the top of my head.  I had a similar problem with my XPages.TV app.  A repeat from a managed bean data source get's messed up when the pager is used.  It's like the pager gets lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm making some assumptions here without seeing your MBean code, but hope to point you in the right direction nonetheless...

Ensure you are restoring the datamodel within the studenLists bean during invocations of the **getStudents()** call.  I see you have **value="#{studentlist.students}"** in the XSP fragment above... that should map to a **getStudents()** method on the bean returning a **DataModel** of Student objects or the like... presumably yes?  So, a couple of things to bear in mind here... ensure the bean is in at least **viewScope** (preferably) and that you "restore the wrapped data" in the getStudents() method based on a **non-transient** buffer (eg: ArrayList that is holding the current set of filtered "student" objects - and make sure that the buffer of Student objects is serializable - critical for "Disk Persistence"!

If you use this approach, the Pager will always be "paging" against an up-to-date restored datamodel for each subsequent paging request posted against the current view - the page index etc being internally managed by the DataModel object.

eg:

**1. No restoration:**

```
    ...
    private transient DataModel studentSearchResults;
    private transient List searchResults;
    ...
    public DataModel getStudents() {
        if (null == studentSearchResults) {
            studentSearchResults = new ListDataModel();
        }
        return studentSearchResults;
    }
```

versus:

**2. With restoration:**

```
    ...
    private transient DataModel studentSearchResults;
    private List searchResults;
    ...
    public DataModel getStudents() {
        if (null == studentSearchResults) {
            studentSearchResults= new ListDataModel();
            if(null != searchResults){
                studentSearchResults.setWrappedData(searchResults);
            }
        }
        return studentSearchResults;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Paul and Tony for your help. Changing the scope of the bean from request to view in the faces-config.xml solved the issue with the pager. Very grateful to all those who helped me troubleshoot this.

Answer (score 0):

Do you also lose the data if you add another button that just partially refreshes the dataTable? That should identify if it's a problem with managed bean properties being reset (in which case the contents of the dataTable would disappear) or a problem with paging (in which case they wouldn't).

Comment: I added a button to the page that does a partial update on the datatable. After I run the search that populates the table, I click on the Refresh Datatable button and it clears the table of data. Is that what you were getting at, Paul?

Comment: Yes. That confirms the problem is in the bean, not the pager. The data is no longer available to the bean after a partial refresh. Maybe the connection details are not being stored in properties in the bean, but just passed when the search is run. If they're stored into properties in the bean and those properties used, that should hopefully solve the problem.